# Как задать дефолтные настройки для скрипта?

Tags: javascript, html, ооп, валидация

Имеется такой ООП(наверное) скрипт для валидации полей на клиенте. Вопрос в том, как выставить дефолтные настройки для некоторых параметров, например есть параметр `phoneCountryCode`, в зависимости от того, `false` он или  `true` зависит регулярное выражение по которому будет проходить валидация формы. Если я просто не добавляю параметр, то автоматически получается `false`, а мне нужно, чтобы по дефолту было `true`.

Так же буду отдельно благодарен за указания на  ошибки, которые я допустил при написании имеющегося скрипта в ООП стиле.

```js
function Validation(options) {
  this.fieldElement = document.querySelector(options.fieldSelector);
  this.typeOfValidation = options.validationType;
  this.warningMessage = options.warningMessage;
  this.classMessageCostumize = options.classMessageCostumize;
  var self = this;


  //Select type of validate field
  this.checkField = function() {
    switch (self.typeOfValidation) {
      case 'email':
        checkEmail()
        break;
      case 'password':
        checkPassword()
        break;
      case 'phone':
        checkPhone()
        break;
    }
  }


  //Function for check Email
  function checkEmail() {
    var regExp = /^\w{1,}@\w{2,}\.\w{2,}$/;
    if (!regExp.test(self.fieldElement.value)) {
      self.showWarningMessage();
    }
  }

  //Function for check Password
  function checkPassword() {
    var regExp = /^\w{1,}@\w{2,}\.\w{2,}$/;
    if (!regExp.test(self.fieldElement.value)) {
      self.showWarningMessage();
    }
  }

  //Function for check Phone
  function checkPhone() {
    var regExp;

    //Checking for validate cpuntry code or no;
    if (options.phoneCountryCode == true) {
      regExp = /^\+\d{12,12}$/;
    } else {
      regExp = /^\d{11,11}$/;
    }

    if (!regExp.test(self.fieldElement.value)) {
      self.showWarningMessage();
    }
  }

  //Add event listener
  this.fieldElement.addEventListener('blur', self.checkField);

  //Warning message

  this.showWarningMessage = function() {
    var parentElement = this.fieldElement.parentNode;
    var messageNode = document.createElement('p');
    messageNode.innerHTML = this.warningMessage;
    messageNode.classList.add(this.classMessageCostumize);
    parentElement.appendChild(messageNode);
  }
}


new Validation({
  fieldSelector: '.input',
  validationType: 'phone',
  buttonSelector: '.button',
  warningMessage: 'Введите корректный телефон',
  classMessageCostumize: 'someClass',
  phoneCountryCode: false,
})
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил сверху 3 строчки кода

```js
function Validation(options) {

  if (typeof options.phoneCountryCode === 'undefined') {
    options.phoneCountryCode = true;
  }

  this.fieldElement = document.querySelector(options.fieldSelector);
  this.typeOfValidation = options.validationType;
  this.warningMessage = options.warningMessage;
  this.classMessageCostumize = options.classMessageCostumize;
  var self = this;


  //Select type of validate field
  this.checkField = function() {
    switch (self.typeOfValidation) {
      case 'email':
        checkEmail()
        break;
      case 'password':
        checkPassword()
        break;
      case 'phone':
        checkPhone()
        break;
    }
  }


  //Function for check Email
  function checkEmail() {
    var regExp = /^\w{1,}@\w{2,}\.\w{2,}$/;
    if (!regExp.test(self.fieldElement.value)) {
      self.showWarningMessage();
    }
  }

  //Function for check Password
  function checkPassword() {
    var regExp = /^\w{1,}@\w{2,}\.\w{2,}$/;
    if (!regExp.test(self.fieldElement.value)) {
      self.showWarningMessage();
    }
  }

  //Function for check Phone
  function checkPhone() {
    var regExp;

    //Checking for validate cpuntry code or no;
    if (options.phoneCountryCode == true) {
      regExp = /^\+\d{12,12}$/;
    } else {
      regExp = /^\d{11,11}$/;
    }

    if (!regExp.test(self.fieldElement.value)) {
      self.showWarningMessage();
    }
  }

  //Add event listener
  this.fieldElement.addEventListener('blur', self.checkField);

  //Warning message

  this.showWarningMessage = function() {
    var parentElement = this.fieldElement.parentNode;
    var messageNode = document.createElement('p');
    messageNode.innerHTML = this.warningMessage;
    messageNode.classList.add(this.classMessageCostumize);
    parentElement.appendChild(messageNode);
  }
}


new Validation({
  fieldSelector: '.input',
  validationType: 'phone',
  buttonSelector: '.button',
  warningMessage: 'Введите корректный телефон',
  classMessageCostumize: 'someClass',
  phoneCountryCode: false,
})
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input">
```

Comment: а если таких параметров много, то для каждого такие строки прописывать думаю топорный вариант, есть еще варианты?

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, можно создать отдельный объект дефолтных значений, в любом случае проверки нужны будут